# Android ffmpeg save and append h264 streamed videos

Tags: android, ffmpeg, append, h.264, rtsp

I need to save a video file generated by two video streams coming from two different sources. I'm using rtsp over tcp/ip, and the videos are encoded with h264.
I need to first record the video from the first source and than continue with the second source.
So what I tried was to declare two AVFormatContext instances, initialize both with `avformat_open_input(&context, "rtsp://......",NULL,&options)`
and then read frames with `av_read_frame(context,&packet)`
and write them in the video file `av_write_frame(oc,&packet);`
It works fine saving the video from the first source, but if by example I saved **y** frames from the first context, when I try reading and saving the frames from the second context in the same file, for the first **y** frames I am tring to save, **`av_write_frame(oc,&packet2);`
would retun -22**, and would not add the frame to the file.

I think the problem is that the context variable remembers how many frames were read, and it gives every read packet an identification number, to make sure it isn't written twice. But when I'm using a new context those identification numbers reset, the AVOutputFormat or the AVFormatContext also retain the id of the package they are expecting to receive, and would not write anything until they receive a package with that id.
Now I'm wondering how could I solve this inconvenience. I can't find any setter for that id, or any way to reuse the same context. I thought to modify the ffmpeg sources but they are pretty complex and I couldn't find what I was looking for.
An alternative would be to save the two video in two different files but, I don't know how to append them afterwards, as ffmpeg can only append videos encoded with mpeg and rencoding the video isn't really an option, as it will take to much time. Also I couldn't find any other functional way to append two mp4 videos encoded with h264.

I'll be happy to hear any kind of usable ideea to this problem.

Comment: Did you find any solution to save RTSP stream in android??

Answer (score 1):

If you are saving raw h.264 streams why not simply store two seperate streams and then concatenate the file chunks on the command line seperately using a system command system("cat file1 file2 > finalfile")

If your output is one of the following you can append directly using cat

1. Transport stream [ts] with same codecs
2. .mpg files
3. raw h.264 files
4. raw mpeg4 files which have exactly same encoding headers [same dimensions, profile and toolsets mentioned in header]
5. H.263 streams

You cannot concatenate directly mp4 files or 3gpp files.

Comment: I need my android application to do this automatically. It wouldn't be too friendly to ask users to use the command line.Is there a way to to this in the application? in C language